# Convert Numbers into Comma Separated Numbers and sort numerically

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am getting hourly sales for the last 3 months

```
USE [SambaPos]
GO
SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR, [LastUpdateTime]) AS [Hour], 
    FORMAT(SUM([TotalAmount]), 'N0') AS [Sales]
FROM
    Tickets
WHERE
    [LastUpdateTime] > 
    DATEADD(MONTH, 
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 
            DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
        ), 0
    ) 
    AND
    [LastUpdateTime] < GETDATE()
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(HOUR, [LastUpdateTime])
ORDER BY
    [Sales] DESC
```

Using Format function formats the numbers in a string and order by on a string column doesn't give numerically sorted numbers. So, how do I preserve the numeric sorting along with string formatting.

Here are the results from string sorted sales, I want them to be numerically sorted by represented in comma separated format.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the raw value in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Try changing your query to the following

```
USE [SambaPos]
GO
SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR, [LastUpdateTime]) AS [Hour], 
    FORMAT(SUM([TotalAmount]), 'N0') AS [Sales]
FROM
    Tickets
WHERE
    [LastUpdateTime] > 
    DATEADD(MONTH, 
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 
            DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
        ), 0
    ) 
    AND
    [LastUpdateTime] < GETDATE()
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(HOUR, [LastUpdateTime])
ORDER BY
    SUM([TotalAmount]) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. 
But SQL seems to work in strange ways. It is worth reading about what SQL allows under different clauses, or how SQL processes the clauses.

Comment: Yes, getting a clear understanding of T-SQL is valuable :-)